# Is there InteliJ Idea equivalent for Eclipse "type filters" feature

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

Let's assume that I have `my.company.Component` class in project. Unfortunately, in JDK libraries there is `java.awt.Component` class available (that I never need to use).

Each time I want to import Component class, IntelJ asks my to decide which one I want to use. It's quite irritating given that I always want to use the same one.

In Eclipse I could use "Type Filters" to exclude packages/classes that I never use. Is there any equivalent for InteliJ?

Comment: When you are prompted to choose an import, you can highlight the import you don't want, press the `->` arrow and you have the option to exclude that import. Otherwise, it's `File -> Settings`, `Editor -> Auto Import`.

Comment: @fge please, convert it to the answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is:

1. press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or the red balb that appears infront of Component [image: Press alt+enter]
2. Select Import Class 
   [image: Select import Class]
3. Select the package you want to exclude and press the arrow to the right. Then select the specific package name you want to exclude[image: exclude the desired package]

The **other** way is to go to settings  (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
Then goto

```
Editor -> Auto import -> Exclude from Import and Completion
```

and add the packages you want to exclude (or remove the ones you excluded by mistake)

[image]

Comment: Thanks I try to answer the way I would have liked the answer to be :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are prompted to choose an import, you can highlight the import you don't want; press the `->` arrow and you have the option to exclude that import, or the package, or even parent packages.

Another option is to be found in `File -> Settings`, then choosing `Editor -> Auto Import`.